# @angular/fire modular equivalent to "compat" code to listen to snapshotChanges

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable, modular

How would I rewrite this function in the latest "modular" version of angular firestore?

```
getLatestEntries(limit = 5) {
return this.db.collectionGroup('Entries', ref => ref.orderBy('finishedTime', 'desc').limit(limit)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => <any>{
    id: a.payload.doc.id,
    changeType: a.type,
    ...<Entry>a.payload.doc.data()
  }))
  );
}
```

The idea is returning an Observable<Entry[]> with the added "changeType" attribute indicating "added/modified/deleted".

I tried using collectionSnapshots(), but they are missing the (change)"type" property. Also tried using docChanges(query(collectionGroup())), but that only returns the single updated document, not all of them like snapshotChanges() used to.

Comment: You can use `collectionChanges()`.

Comment: @N.F. Fantastic, thanks! Could not find this anywhere.. thanks a lot!